# How to increment variable

Tags: cmake

In a CMake script, how to increment a variable ?

I was expecting a function like "increment(VAR)" but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
MATH(EXPR VAR "${VAR}+1")
```

[CMake documentation](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3amath)

Comment: +1, but CMake is so nasty. Why the hell don't they just implement direct simple/basic mathematical inline expressions!? Or a freaking return value for functions!? Most frustrating language ever seen.

Comment: CMake is a tool that serves the purpose of configuring and building (using the underlying tools) a project. If you start putting "simple/basic" things that are normally not required by the process of creating the configuration files (from the CMakeLists.txt) the thing will become even more overbloated than it is. CMake is not a general purpose programming language.

Comment: @rbaleksandar No, that's not how it works. Adding the faculties of a programming language will prevent it from becoming bloated in the first place. I worked with Bazel for a year before switching to Cmake. Cmake is a nightmare of complexity and bloat. With Bazel, it's simply and easy to implement custom features (eventually required by most large projects) because behind the scenes it's just python.

Comment: @JacobSharf I've worked with many different build systems at different scales, and it's not cmake that's the extra nightmare, it is the baggage people bring when they insist on using it like a general purpose programming language, compounded by the fact that Pre-3.x cmake didn't give you much choice.