# In a C Make script, how to increment a variable?

Tags: view, increment

I was expecting a function like "increment(VAR)" but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

`MATH(EXPR VAR "${VAR}+1")`

Review this

- [How to increment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485227/how-to-increment-variable)
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3amath

Answer (score 0):

The proffered solution won't work in every context, but only in the context of an ACTION that corresponds to a given target.

Also, not sure what all this MATH jazz is, how about using backticks (prefer $()-notation, but that's ksh-specific):

**`expr ${VAR} + 1`**

You can barely see the backticks before the 'e' and after the '1', but they're there.